# Remove rules with command Remove-InboxRule

Tags: powershell

I would like to remove by filtering "**Filter ***" a massive rules. Have this command but can't run correctly

```
Remove-InboxRule -Mailbox user@domain.com -Identity 'Filter *' -Confirm:$false
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly you want to remove all rules from a mailbox.  The identity parameter doesn't allow for wildcards, so in that regard there is no filtering capability.  -Identity does support pipeline input, so you can however pipe the results of Get-InboxRule:

```
Get-Mailbox user@domain.com | Get-InboxRule | Remove-InboxRule -WhatIf
```

OR:

```
Get-InboxRule -Mailbox user@domain.com | Remove-InboxRule -WhatIf
```

You can insert additional filtering via a Where clause between Get-InboxRule and Remove-InboxRule:

Example:

```
Get-Mailbox user@domain.com | Get-InboxRule | Where{$_.MoveToFolder -eq "Junk E-Mail"} | Remove-InboxRule -WhatIf
```

I have to caution you that any rules that had been un-checked in Outlook will get deleted any time you change rules from the shell  I've worked on this a lot in the past and the only API that seems not to have this issue is the Outlook Object Model.  ESM, EWS, CDO & RDO (deprecated as they are) all have the same issue.  So if you are just trying to wipe everything you're good, but if you're filtering first, exercise caution.

Comment: But it's possible to remove filters start with 'Filter *' for example "Filter one, Filer 2, Filter 3,..."?

Comment: The *-InboxRule cmdlets lack filtering capabilities.  -Identity doesn't support "*" or multiple values, which might have looked similar to your last comment.  No -Filter Param either

Unfortunately leveraging the pipe is the best alternative I see.

Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-inboxrule?view=exchange-ps

Note: These cmdlets aren't fast, but I can't describe that in a comment.